# CSV download instead of display Laravel 7 on Nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I am having an issue getting a file to download on my production server.
Using different browsers gives the same results, success on test server, downloads as a file without changing current page.
On production server however it simply opens a new tab and displays the csv as text on the page.
I can only figure its to do with the server (Nginx).
Can I change the server block to give correct behaviour.

**Javascript Client side code**

```
window.open('myfile.csv');
```

**Laravel controller code**

```
protected function download(){
    $filename=$_GET["filename"];
    //return response()->download(public_path()."/downloads".$filename);

    $fileContent = file_get_contents($filename);

    $response = response($fileContent, 200, [
        'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"',
    ]);
    return $response;
}
```

**Response Headers:**

Test Server

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 318
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Mon, 27 Apr 2020 16:29:06 GMT
ETag: "5ea70851-13e"
Last-Modified: Mon, 27 Apr 2020 16:29:05 GMT
Server: nginx/1.16.1
```

Production Server

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Mon, 27 Apr 2020 16:32:00 GMT
ETag: W/"5ea70900-13e"
Expires: Mon, 27 Apr 2020 16:31:59 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 27 Apr 2020 16:32:00 GMT
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

I only have control over the virtual server block on production. To confirm, following several helpful posts - the code WORKS on test server and all browsers, DOES NOT WORK on production server and all browsers.

Comment: Do you want to download the CSV file? if yes, you can use `<a>` tag.  Try `<a href="path/to/csvfile/" download>Download CSV</a>`

Comment: Yes, the csv file is dynamic name tho, would prefer not to use dhtml hacks, the question is why does the test server work exactly as intended but not production, it's the same code.

Comment: `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
  header("Cache-control: private");
  header("Content-type: application/force-download");
  header("Content-transfer-encoding: binary\n");`

Comment: Thanks, could you clarify this in an answer

Comment: Try these headers in your code, specially content-type, might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected function download() {
    $filename = public_path() . "/downloads" . $_GET["filename"];
    $fileContent = file_get_contents($filename);
    return response($fileContent, 200,
        [
            'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"'
        ]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following:

```
function downloadFile(fileName, type="text/plain") {
  // Create an invisible A element
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(a);

  // Set the HREF to a Blob representation of the data to be downloaded
  a.href = url;

  // Use download attribute to set set desired file name
  a.setAttribute("download", fileName);

  // Trigger the download by simulating click
  a.click();

  // Cleanup
  document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

Let me know If you get any errors.

Hope it helps you

Thank you

Comment: unfortunately not, while this is valid code, thanks, the issue is why the 2 nginx servers handle the code differently, as updated on the question code WORKS on test server and all browsers, DOES NOT WORK on production server and all browsers

Comment: I do have faced this kind of thing where such things work like charm in local but not in production. The reason could be a server configuration

Comment: marked down as not the answer and getting hassled to accept this as the answer, sorry